# How to organize multithreaded access via the rest api to a resource using Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, rest, concurrency, java-11

I would want organize multithreaded access via the rest api to a resource using Spring Boot.

There is information (I found it here) that SrpingBoot can parallelize requests (which I doubt) to the controller with scope-singlotone.

How to start the design of such a controller, or what approach to apply for this?

Comment: Link is not added correctly

Comment: Which link ? I didn't specify the link here in the description of the question.

Comment: You have added this "(I found it here)". I thought you meant a link.

Answer (score 0):

Spring handles requests in parallel - that means your singleton controllers have to be thread-safe.

If you have a single resource which cannot handle parallel access you have to use Java's `synchronized` or locks to serialize the access.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your answer confused me. RestController already has properties for processing parallel requests to its resources, or you need to do something else additionally. could you give an example of what you meant .

Comment: do RestController already has properties for processing parallel requests to its resources, or you need to do something else additionally? In previous comment had a question, sorry.

Comment: A controller in Spring is typically a singleton - meaning there is only one instance for the whole application. Request will be handled in parallel by the underlying container (Tomcat, Jetty, etc.). This means that the controller is always used in multiple threads (in parallel). You can easily test this by creating a break point in your controller and then hitting your API multiple time (in IntelliJ be sure to not break the whole VM with your breakpoint - which is the default).

Answer (score 0):

Spring Rest Controllers do handle request using a thread pool. Since Spring beans are singleton, your Spring Beans should be `Stateless` or we can say bean should have a `sheared state`. Which means you cannot have a state that will change with the time.

Comment: I still wanted to clarify. Even when beans for web, service, and dao layers, have a singleton scope? And how does it work ? I do not observe this action (multithreaded processing). Although Singleton is made thread-safe, it can only be used by one thread at a time. That is, when the request came, the main thread creates a child thread ? Then the child thread how does it work with beans ? While it is working . are the other threads waiting ?